# Calculate MapBounds for a given a Latitude/Longitude, Area and Aspect ratio

Tags: c#, geolocation, geography

I have a starting location (lat/long) and an area to search in square meters.
There is also an aspect ratio width and height provided (e.g 1000, 500).

Examples

So if I have an area of 4000sqm, and an aspect ratio of (1, 1) the resulting bounding box would be 1000m north, south, east, west of the starting point.

With an area 4000sqm and aspect ratio (2, 1) then the resulting box should be 2000 meters east and west of the starting point and 500m north and south of the starting location, giving a bounding box of 4sq km that adheres to the aspect ratio.